# How to make a vector of a type and its name?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++17, stdvector

I have several classes, and I want to make their objects. Each object has a different name. To differentiate with any other object (maybe of same type).
I want to give the responsibility of making objects to a different function, which takes a vector of {name, class type} elements. Let's say I have 2 structs:

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B { int i; double d; };

struct Type
{
    std::string name;

    template<typename T>
    T t;

    template<typename T>
    using type = decltype(t);
};

std::vector<Type> v{ {"ObjA1", A()}, {"ObjB", B()}, {"ObjA2", A()} };

void fun(std::vector<Type> vec)
{
    // use vec to create objects
}
```

- Is this possible to achieve ?
- Structures `A` and `B` are actually classes, provided by some
  external framework.

Comment: An essential feature of a `std::vector` is that all elements are of same type. To achieve what you want, you have to add some limitation or extension: Either derive all different classes from the same base class and make the element type of the `std::vector` a pointer (or smart pointer) to that base type. An alternative could be to store a `std::vector<std::variant<...>>` but then you have to know/name all types (for `std::variant`) beforehand.

Comment: Dear john I know templates sufficiently well. Anything related to solution, you want to offer ?

Comment: @Scheff's Cat  Deriving from a base is not possible here, as theses classes are provided by external framework. Thanks for your answer, I must try Any :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have several classes, and I want to make their objects....
>
> Is this possible to achieve ?

Yes, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can. Since you know the types, I would suggest a [`std::variant<A, B, ...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) as a template parameter to the `std::vector<Type<...>>`.

This required however your `struct Type` be a class template.

```
template<typename T> struct Type
{
    std::string name;
    T t;    
    using type = decltype(t);
};
```

Then we can provide a helper alias type:

```
#include <variant>

// helper type alias for variats
template<typename... Ts>
using VariantsType = Type<std::variant<Ts...>>;
```

Now you can write

```
std::vector<VariantsType<A, B, C>> v{
    {"ObjA1", A{}}, {"ObjB", B{}}, {"ObjA2", A{}}
};
v.emplace_back(VariantsType<A, B, C>{"ObjA3", A{}});
v.emplace_back(VariantsType<A, B, C>{"ObjC1", C{}});
// ... so on
```

**[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9h9YW9hKP)**

Comment: Seems good, I must try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what type will be used, you can use [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).
If you can not list the types you will use, you can use [any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).
Like

```
  std::vector<std::any> example;
  example.push_back(1);
  example.push_back("1");
  example.push_back(std::make_pair(1, "1"));
```